# Existence of an element with a particular order in alternating group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

There are two questions in my Groups and Symmetries textbook (Contemporary Abstract Algebra 9th Edition) that is:

1. "Show that $A_8$ contains an element of order 15"
2. "Find an element of $A_{12}$ of order 30".

I do not understand how to even approach these permutations problems after reading through the chapter twice. I've looked at final answer and the make no sense to me. The answers for them is supposed to be:

1. $|(123)(45678)| = 15$
2. $(12345)(678)(9,10)(11,12)$ in $A_{12}$ has order 30

How did they even come to that conclusion? For 1. I do know the order of $(123)$ is 3 and for $(45678)$ its 5 and their product gives 15 but how do we know that $(123)(45678)$ is an element in $A_8$ for sure.

Comment: The sign of a cycle of length $k$ is $(-1)^{k-1}$, this is a basic result. Also, sign is a homomorphism. So the sign of $(123)(45678)$ is $(-1)^2\cdot (-1)^4=1$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Contemporary Abstract Algebra 9th Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recognise even and odd permutations by their cycle-type when they are written as products of disjoint cycles.

Cycles of even length (eg transpositions) are odd permutations.
Cycles of odd length are even permutations.

[You should check whether your text book proves this, or gives it as an exercise - the fact is basic and fundamental, and the proof should be there somewhere]

Then the product of two odd permutations is an even permutation (etc).

So for a product of disjoint cycles to be an odd permutation, an odd number of the cycles would have to be odd permutations. And this would mean an odd number of cycles of even length.

Otherwise the permutation is even - if the number cycles of even length is even (and note that zero is an even number).

Comment: I do not understand it. Lets say I want to find out if there exists an element of order 42 in $A_{13}$. My work so far is that $(1234567)(8,9, 10)(11,12,13) \in A_{13}$. But the $lcm(7,3)$ gives 21. It doesnt answer anything about what was asked

Comment: So you need a $7-$cycle and either a $6-$cycle (which gives a result which is odd odd and not in the alternating group) or a $3-$cycle and a $2-cycle$ (at least) to give a element of order $42$. But the cycle type $7, 3, 2$ is an odd permutation, and you would need an additional $2$ to get back to even, and that can't be done because you don't have $14$ elements to permute.